# Unable to find zuul properties in application.yml

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

Unable to find below zuul properties in application.yml attached the pom.xml.
I hope I added the necessary dependency or do I missing anything.
How to connect the services with gateway.

**application.yml**

```
zuul.routes.hello.path=/hello/**
zuul.routes.hello.serviceId=Beginner-Microservice
```

[image]

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

The reference link

https://javabeginnerstutorial.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-2-microservices-with-netflix-zuul-api-gateway/

The spring cloud version which I have used is

```
<spring-cloud.version>Finchley.M8</spring-cloud.version>
```

Kindly help me in this regard

Comment: Asking about auto completion vs zuul working are two different things. Is zuul working correctly?

Comment: How do we ensure Zuul working? since currently i'm able to start the server but to configure the service we need this property zuul.routes.<<service>>

Comment: this is a problem with cloud version <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.M8</spring-cloud.version> using <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.SR3</spring-cloud.version> i'm able to get properties

Comment: Not surprising. M8 is a pre-release milestone and is not supported.

Comment: I just started learning and implemented it, I have also given a source link of an example, but like me most would not aware, it might be surprising for beginners, that why I have not added to a solution and if you might aware of it then your point should in first comment